# Javascript Parse A SearchParams Query String

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, format

How can we possibly parse the sample data below.

## Search param

```
let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(locals.filters.searchkeys)

            console.log("Search",  urlSearchParams)

Result :  { 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW,Cadillac' }
```

## Desired output format

{ 'Year' : '2019,2018', 'Make' : 'Acura,BMW,Cadillac' }

Comment: Were you aware of `URLSearchParams.entries()` before posting the question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries It seems to me that this detail is missed in both the question and the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck answer does mention and use entries, can you tell me what seems to be missing to you ?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed in the snippet, but the answer is not clear: "entries using entries method" is a little confusing when you do not know about `URLSearchParams.entries()` and you are also referring to similarly named `Object.fromEntries`. A link to the MDN would go along way in my opinion.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck `You can get entries using entries method, and then build object using Object.fromEntries,` first sentence in the answer talk about how you can get entries from Urlsearchparams, isn't it 

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the word __entries__ anywhere in the question.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck apologies typo, I meant answer

Comment: Op can you tell me why previously selected answer is sufficient now ? I am happy to know if I missed something in my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get entries using entries method, and then build object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
let searchQuery = `Year=2019&Make=Acura,BMW,Cadillac`
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchQuery)

let obj = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams.entries()])

console.log(obj)
```

If your environment doesn't support Object.fromEntries you can use reduce

```js
let searchQuery = `Year=2019&Make=Acura,BMW,Cadillac`
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchQuery)

let obj = [...searchParams.entries()].reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  op[key] = value
  return op
},{})

console.log(obj)
```